# How do I say "put my foot down"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to say that I have had enough, put my foot down.

It's time to put my foot down, do not start again.

I am putting my foot down, on the unannounced visits.

It is time to put my foot down, with the needless interruptions.

Comment: maybe add some example sentences?

Comment: Examples have been added, per request.

Comment: What is your attempt at translation?

Comment: Jack, what Igor meant was that normally your questions show that you tried to make such a sentence in Japanese on your own, but that you want someone to double check or correct them... In this question though, you're simply asking for translation help, which is contrary to the goals of the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say:

・「絶対{ぜったい}に許{ゆる}さない。」

・「絶対に譲{ゆず}らない。」

・「断固{だんこ}とした態度{たいど}をとる。」

・「きっぱりとした態度をとる。」

Comment: but would you actually say these things to the person you're speaking to as part of your insistence that something never happen again? For example, would you include these words in a sentence when speaking to your husband/wife/boyfriend/girlfriend, about their friends coming to visit unannounced, or about being interrupted?  Also I think Jack was asking, is there a common Japanese idiom similar to "put my foot down"?